# Storing a truffle contract interface in version control

Tags: contract-development, truffle, contract-deployment

#### What I'm doing

When I compile and deploy a contract using Truffle, I get a `.json` build artifact that contains information about where the contract is deployed on the network (its address).

So far I have just been checking this file into version control in order to distribute the interface to my contract, but this is less than ideal since the artifact file [contains the compiled binary of the contract](https://github.com/melonproject/protocol/blob/f0cc599300dc12f143126430a51cee78993b51b0/build/contracts/BitcoinToken.json#L268).

#### Why it's bad

Since git is not meant to handle binaries, changes to a binary make the repo unnecessarily large, and diffs become extremely noisy.

My question is this:

*How can I distribute an interface to my deployed contract without checking a binary into version control?*

#### "Solutions" I can think of

- I am aware of git-annex and similar solutions, but they seem like overkill.
- I've also thought about doing something like:
  `truffle networks > networks.txt` 
  but this is hacky and requires consumers to create their own interface with the contract addresses I distribute.

Comment: We only commit the .sol files in the repository. Only after deployment we generate a document with the contracts addresses and abis (which are JSON).

Comment: @Ismael ok, but you don't distribute the .json, is that right?
How can someone know the addresses of your contracts after they've been deployed?

Comment: It's part of the documentation, we add to a section in the readme, deployment address and contract abi, also the abi is in a separate file for those who need it that way. But this is done once, after deployment.